# Separate DB for Meteor.users in Meteor App

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app, and I was wondering if there is a way to configure the app to use one Mongo database for users, and a different database for the rest of the app data.  The goal here is to eventually have multiple apps that share the same user accounts database, but each have their own unique app database.  Is this possible with Meteor?

Comment: If you are using a provider like MongoHQ or your own infrastructure, setting the same port should work

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that would work.  Do you mean there's someway to configure Meteor to use certain ports for certain collections?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. What I told you was basically to access the same Mongo instance for all apps but this won't serve your purpose of having a unique app database. You should try the answer below though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I appreciate the great answers for this question, this currently cannot be done in Meteor (as of 0.5.9).  Of course, one could modify the source to make something like this happen, but I'm using Meteor to avoid writing all the boiler-plate plumbing code myself.  Hopefully, this option will be added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) on your meteor server. You could access data on the client using `Meteor.call`. Though I've never tried it it should work. It would also be a nice chance to check out [meteor's new](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA-QB9rQCq8&feature=youtu.be) [npm system](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/engine).

Server js

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap.require;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Server = mongo.Server, Db = mongo.Db, BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var client = new Db('test', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {w: 1})
...
```

You won't have reactivity though unless you write your own methods to check the database.

Comment: okay, so basically, I would have to set this up, and then use this setup for all of my app-specific non-user collections, right?  And then still allow meteor to handle all the user data.  Is that what you're getting at?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Meteor.connect()? It lets you connect to an external Meteor app's DB.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_connect

Edit: I've never tried it for users (that Collection is somehow different from "ordinary" collections I guess), but I guess it should work.